# Which C++ library to use for color quantizing images with user-defined palette and dithering?

Tags: library, c++, image-processing

I'm making a C++ application, and I want to quantize the colors in a imported image, using a fixed palette with optional dithering. Ideally, with many dithering algorithms for a user to choose from. This quantized image will then be passed to a later part of the program.

The problem is, I can't find a library that satisfies these conditions. Here are the libraries I've looked at (note, this is my own observations and I may be overlooking stuff):

- **OpenCV**

  - I decided that it's WAY overkill for what I'm doing
- **Leptonica**

  - http://www.leptonica.org/color-quantization.html
  - Supports quantization (`colorquant1.c` & `colorquant2.c`)

    - Supports dithering, *not sure which algorithm*
    - *Doesn't appear to support user-set palette (maybe the static helper `pixQuantizeWithColormap()`??)*
    - *Doesn't appear to support color bleed reduction (multiplying error values by a constant <=1 in order to make the algorithm less "bold" when choosing a color for a pixel)*
- **Magick++ (ImageMagick)**

  - https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/
  - https://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image++.html#Image%20Manipulation%20Methods
  - Easy to understand high-level functions
  - Supports quantization

    - Supports Floyd-Steinberg dithering (`Image.quantize()` w/ `quantize-
      Dither == true`)

      - It also supports Bayer (`Image.randomThreshold("2x2")`), *but in B/W only (I know Bayer or some other ordered dithering algorithm definitely has a color version. There's one in GIMP.)*
      - ImageMagick itself also supports Riemersma, *but it doesn't appear it's implemented in Magick++*
    - ImageMagick supports user-set palettes, but *this also does not appear to be implemented in Magick++*
    - *Doesn't appear to support color bleed reduction*

So is there a library that fits my purpose? Did I miss something while reading docs? Please note that I'll be using the library for other image processing as well, like cropping and reading individual pixels.

Answer (score 0):

[nQuantCpp](https://github.com/mcychan/nQuantCpp) includes top 6 color quantization algorithms for visual c++ producing high quality optimized images.

As you mentioned about Riemersma, Generalized Hilbert ("gilbert") space-filling curve for rectangular domains of arbitrary (non-power of two) sizes which can dither better than the Hilbert curve visits every point in a square grid with a size of any other power of 2.